# why is the markdown geany plugin missing from the repository?

Tags: plugins, geany

The geany plugin web page suggests it thinks 'markdown' should be in the group plugin package but on downloading there is no code for that particular function. The author has shown me where to get the source, but there is no point me compiling it if someone more knowledgeable than me has taken a positive step to omit it. Is this a webkit issue?

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question is contained in package [changelog](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/g/geany-plugins/geany-plugins_1.37+dfsg-6build1/changelog):

> geany-plugins (1.32+dfsg-3) unstable; urgency=medium
>
> - [67b34ed] Disable webkit-using plugins: markdown, webhelper
>   webkitgtk-3.0 is not to be used as it is deprecated, but the port to
>   webkit2gtk-4.0 isn't ready yet.

Then the Markdown plugin was re-enabled starting with version 1.37+dfsg-5 which came with 21.04.

So currently there [are two Ubuntu versions](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=geany%20markdown) with `geany-plugin-markdown` package - 21.04 and 21.10.

---

If you need to compile `geany-markdown-plugin` on 18.04 LTS use the patching and compiling method below:

```
software-properties-gtk # enable Source Code here, reload the lists

# get
sudo apt-get build-dep geany-plugins
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev fakeroot

cd ~/Downloads
apt-get source geany-plugins
cd geany-plugins-1.32+dfsg

# patch
sed -i "s/--disable-peg-markdown/--enable-peg-markdown/" debian/rules
sed -i "s/--disable-markdown/--enable-markdown/" debian/rules

cat <<\EOF > ~/Downloads/debian-control.patch
55c55
< #        geany-plugin-markdown (>= ${source:Version}),
---
>          geany-plugin-markdown (>= ${source:Version}),
469,478c469,478
< # Package: geany-plugin-markdown
< # Enhances: geany
< # Architecture: any
< # Depends: ${geany:ABI}, geany-plugins-common (= ${binary:Version}),
< #         ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
< # Description: markdown plugin for Geany
< #  This plugin provides a real-time preview of rendered Markdown in Geany.
< #  .
< #  Geany is a small and lightweight integrated development environment using the
< #  Gtk+ toolkit.
---
> Package: geany-plugin-markdown
> Enhances: geany
> Architecture: any
> Depends: ${geany:ABI}, geany-plugins-common (= ${binary:Version}),
>          ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
> Description: markdown plugin for Geany
>   This plugin provides a real-time preview of rendered Markdown in Geany.
>   .
>   Geany is a small and lightweight integrated development environment using the
>   Gtk+ toolkit.
EOF
patch debian/control < ~/Downloads/debian-control.patch

# compile, build and install
cd ~/Downloads && apt-get source -b geany-plugins
sudo apt-get install ./geany-plugin-markdown_1.32+dfsg-3_amd64.deb
```

Then launch Geany and enable the plugin from in it using *Tools → Plugin Manager* and enjoy.

For Ubuntu 20.04 LTS this method may be adapted as follows:

```
software-properties-gtk # enable Source Code here, reload the lists

# get
sudo apt-get build-dep geany-plugins
sudo apt-get install libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev fakeroot

cd ~/Downloads
apt-get source geany-plugins
cd geany-plugins-1.36+dfsg

# patch
sed -i "s/--disable-peg-markdown/--enable-peg-markdown/" debian/rules
sed -i "s/--disable-markdown/--enable-markdown/" debian/rules

cat <<\EOF > ~/Downloads/debian-control.patch
55c55
< #        geany-plugin-markdown (>= ${source:Version}),
---
>          geany-plugin-markdown (>= ${source:Version}),
469,478c469,478
< # Package: geany-plugin-markdown
< # Enhances: geany
< # Architecture: any
< # Depends: ${geany:ABI}, geany-plugins-common (= ${binary:Version}),
< #         ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
< # Description: markdown plugin for Geany
< #  This plugin provides a real-time preview of rendered Markdown in Geany.
< #  .
< #  Geany is a small and lightweight integrated development environment using the
< #  Gtk+ toolkit.
---
> Package: geany-plugin-markdown
> Enhances: geany
> Architecture: any
> Depends: ${geany:ABI}, geany-plugins-common (= ${binary:Version}),
>          ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
> Description: markdown plugin for Geany
>   This plugin provides a real-time preview of rendered Markdown in Geany.
>   .
>   Geany is a small and lightweight integrated development environment using the
>   Gtk+ toolkit.
EOF
patch debian/control < ~/Downloads/debian-control.patch

# compile, build and install
cd ~/Downloads && apt-get source -b geany-plugins
sudo apt-get install ./geany-plugin-markdown_1.36+dfsg-1_amd64.deb
```